# Is finder search supposed to work as "full text search" at all in OS X El Capitan?

Tags: finder, spotlight, macos, search

Scenario: I am trying to find a picture (which is named DSC_2345.jpg) inside the Photos Library in Finder. When I type "234" (without quotes) directly in the finder search field, all the photos whose names contain "234" are displayed in finder; however, when I type "2345" (without quotes) no photos. When I Type DSC_2345 I see the photo.

So my question is:

Is this full text search just supported with a maximum of 3 digits? It seems strange to me... I had a similar strange Finder search problem somehow also in Yosemite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finder** uses **Spotlight** to index and search for files and folders.  There are several resources that can help you with understanding the way **Spotlight** indexes files on your Mac.

Since you are looking for an exact phrase type of text search, use quotation marks.  (See below)

In **Finder** select the Help menu and type in Spotlight for further information.

### [image: Spotlight Help]

[Apple support: If searching your Mac doesn’t return expected results](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21903?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US)

From Apple's Support site regarding unexpected search results:

> **OS X El Capitan: If searching your Mac doesn’t return expected results**
>   There are several things you can try if a search doesn’t return the
>   items you expect.
>
> **Check the text you entered in the search field**
>   Make sure the word or
>   phrase is spelled correctly.
>
> ***To search for an exact phrase, enclose it in quotation marks.***
>   For example, enter “trip to Paris” to find items that contain that exact
>   phrase. If you don’t use quotation marks, the search results include
>   items that contain those words in any order.
>
> **Check the location you’re searching**
>   If you began your search in Spotlight, the search results can include email, Calendar events,
>   Spotlight Suggestions, information from other apps, and more. If you
>   began your search in a Finder window, the search results include only
>   files and folders on your internal disk.
>
> **Check your Spotlight preferences**
>   You may have removed items from Spotlight search results. Choose Apple menu > System Preferences,
>   click Spotlight, then click Search Results.
>
> You may have excluded certain folders or disks from searches. Choose
>   Apple menu > System Preferences, click Spotlight, then click Privacy.
>
> You may have turned off Location Services for Spotlight Suggestions.
>   For more information, see About Spotlight Suggestions.
>
> For more information about Spotlight preferences, see Spotlight
>   preferences.